# In Interop.Excel, the Worksheet.SaveAs has a CSV option. How can I use this if my *.xlsx file has line feeds in some cells (Alt+Enter)

Tags: excel, csv, excel-interop, linefeed

Writing a c# app to digest some old spreadsheets.  When reading an Excel file that contains line feeds (by using Alt-Enter while in a cell), I can't seem to use "Worksheet.SaveAs" to save a CSV file.  It treats the linefeed as a carriage return and a new cell.

Interop.Excel should recognize the linefeeds and remove them during the save.
[Sample Table and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZBra.png)

Comment: Let's assume Excel *could* handle this correctly. What would your target CSV look like ? This is no concept of "cells" in CSV files. You could try to iterate the cells and replace linefeed with a marker character, which would work in CSV export.

Comment: A CSV file uses commas AND the end of a line to delimit its values.  I could see values like, "1, abc,,  , 2b, January 1, 2022, a line \r with a linefeed, c, d".   Any special characters are cast into a string equivalent, so all characters of an Excel cell are within the commas of a CSV element.